# C++ Socket Programming- Finding client machines IP, TrueIP, and bind port

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

I am having some trouble figuring out how to fill out a custom UDP header. The client normally connects to a server/port specified in the arguments, and optionally it also accepts a relay IP and port number, the relay then uses the info in the header to forward to the server. Currently the program works if provided a raw IP address (i.e. 127.0.0.1), however I cannot get the relay to function properly.

I am using the following arguments:

```
    clientport=atoi(argv[5]); //port on current machine to bind (default 0)
    relayport=atoi(argv[4]);  //port on relay to connect to
    relay = argv[3];          //relay IP
    port = atoi(argv[2]);     //server port
    servername = argv[1];     //server IP
```

I need to fill out the following in my header for the relay (in network byte order):

```
uint32_t from_IP, to_IP;  // Ultimate destination, not the relay
uint32_t trueFromIP, trueToIP; // AWS may change public IP vs private IP
uint16_t from_Port, to_Port; // Ultimate source & destination, Not relay
```

1. I understand that if 0 is provided for the clientport it will choose any port (this happens by default when binding), how can I figure out which port is chosen and include it as 'from_port'?
2. How do I get the client machine's IP address, and "true" IP address?
3. How can I detect if a hostname is used as an argument rather than an IP address, and how would I code it so either would work? Right now I am using something like :

   inet_aton(servername OR relay, &server.sin_addr);

to fill out the sin_addr for the server/relay's sockaddr_in, which only works if provided an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

1. after you call `bind()`, you can use `getsockname()` to find out the port that `bind()` chose.
2. a machine can have multiple IPs install, so to get the "true" IP, you need to know which specific NIC/Adapter is being used to communicate with the relay, and then you can retrieve that NIC/Adapter's IP.  There is nothing in the socket API for getting that IP, you need to use platform-specific APIs instead, like `GetAdaptersInfo()`/`GetAdapterAddresses()` on Windows, or `getifaddrs()` on other platforms.  Once you have decided on a particular NIC/adapter, you can `bind()` the client socket to that IP.
3. use `getaddrinfo()`, or just parse the string yourself using platform-specific APIs, like `WSAStringToAddress()` or `RtlIpv(4/6)StringToAddress()` on Windows.